# Strength of RFI to clip 1mV signal

Tags: filter

How do you compute the strength of radio frequency interference (RFI) that can clip a 1mV signal from typical EKG, EMG and any standard biopotential measuring equipment?

[image]

Supposed the green sine wave (top) is the 1mV signal, and the red sine wave is the RFI (radiated.) What would the strength of the RFI be before it can clip the 1mV signal such that the output (at the bottom) would become distorted?

I'm talking of radiated RFI interference, not from EMI from power supply lines because I used batteries, so it is disconnected from main.

Comment: I assume your question is deeper than the trivial (i.e. read it directly off the diagram given), but I cannot tell to what extent you want/expect an answer. RFI applied to what? Measured where [else]? Why is the amplifier susceptible to interference, why isn't it shielded or filtered?  Why is RFI apparently below the signal frequency? (Not that this is necessarily unusual, but knowing the relative ranges of RFI to reject, and signal to pass, would be useful.)

Comment: It is a bioamplifier input that measures the skin biopotentials, that's why the signals are low in the milliVolt only. I heard RFI can clip it. To what extend it can really clip it and how strong must it be to clip it? This is for typical bioamplifier like EEG, EKG, EMG, etc. and hence true for all standard equipments related to them.

Comment: You have to test it. Data sheets won't tell you, and the answer will depend on the specifics of the circuit.

Comment: The literal answer is the amplifier clipping amplitude minus 1mV (since your 1 mV signal uses up 1mV of dynamic range).  Is that what you really want to know?  Seems like there is probably a deeper question here that you want to ask.

Comment: I just got the figure from elsewhere. i just want to know how RFI can clip milliVolt signal. It is possible it doesnt clip it at all and bioamplifiers dont need any RFI filters at input?

Comment: Both are possible; there are many kinds of amplifiers, and connections of them.  There are many levels of RFI as well, and you would need to specify a test level, and test condition (how the instrument is wired, e.g. to a virtual patient).

Comment: It's just a typical EMG amplifier where the signal measured is between 1 to 10mV. So just share what kind of interferences (RFI, EMI, whatever) from high frequency can distort the signal that it won't be recognizable anymore. The EMG is wired using differential signal with active, reference and ground in the patient as is usual. Please answer using this context.

Comment: Do you expect a single tittle-tattle free number, like for example 71.2 millivolts? Or should it be something about the devices which create the disturbing signals? What about those devices?

Comment: Well. Someone just told me to use RFI filter to avoid clipping the outputs. So please tell me how exactly and how often RFI filters can clip or cause non-linearities in the outputs. Maybe it's not important if you don't live beside the microwave tower or radio stations?  Does it happen in a typical city with ambient background electromagnetic environment with hundreds of radio stations, tv stations, cellular tower all around, or does the non-linearities only occur when you are directly below a microwave disc, radar or the like? Context is beginner so pls write Answer with this context.

Answer (score 1):

No answer.

The sources of the disturbing radiowaves cover all frequencies from few kHz to tens of gigahertzes. Bioelectric measurement systems catch differently different frequencies and the absolutely same mixture of disturbing radiowaves can cause totally different disturbing voltages to different systems and even to the same system when the wires are placed a little differently.

Measurement amplifier devices can have input filters which try to suppress the caught radio frequency voltages before they reach the actual amplifying circuit inside the amplifier. Different amplifier devices have different filters which affect differently at different frequencies and different amplifying circuits inside the amplifiers tolerate different radio frequency voltage amplitudes; the tolerance depend on the frequency.

The caused interference depends drastically on the properties and the constellation of the disturbing signal sources, what's the used measurement system, how it's set up (wiring, settings) and the used RFI countermeasures like a shielding tent + a muscled and vigilant bouncer at the door who helps some people to want to keep out. I mean the people who cannot live without radio devices like phones, bigger size pawing glasses, bluetooth phones etc..

You are right - caught unwanted radio signals can cause clipping which finally generates unwanted noise-like voltages which make the actual bioelectric signal unrecognizable. Even the baseline on the monitor can spread to cover the whole screen height in severe cases. Clipping in the sensor amplifier cannot be filtered out afterwards, because the information "what's the actual bioelectric signal" is lost.

But do not expect the genuine answer to the question could be some single universal limit number of volts, which covers all systems, all ways to use them and all noise sources.

If you have a bioelectric measurement system you can test how it behaves in current radio noise conditions. The conditions can be varied by carrying in some phones , computers, wifi-networks etc, all just under intense usage. Do not expect the result is valid for other systems or even the same system with different cabling.

Comment: Hi, I used a Netech EEG and ECG sine wave generator/simulator. I can create 10 microVolt sine wave and 1 mV sine wave on the BMA-200 bioamplifier. I can't see any noises. This was why I was asking the strength of RFI to distort the sine waves. So kindly give some figure the strength of RFI that can distort the sine wave generated. Thanks.

Comment: It cannot be given, A phone can easily induce much higher voltage, say one volt peak to peak to a wire when the distance between the phone and the wire is short enough and the cellular tower is distant. Amp BMA-200 has a filter. If the filter or at least a part of it is in the input and the amp device is properly built it's possible that no interference exists. Connect a real biopotential measuring connector pair to the amp and your skin, turn gain up, turn amp's speaker ON  and listen if a phone (in use) creates the same rattle as one can hear for ex. in poorly built music players.

Comment: I have traced the entire BMA-200 in Inkscape. It has no filter at the input. It only has overvoltage protection using 4 diodes at input.

Comment: Filtering can happen also as parasitic operation of the measurement cables, connectors, circuit board and parts connected. Most of us have probably seen BMA-200 in advertisements or nowhere. You have an alive real thing. So, make some real tests with real radio transmitters including phones, wifi-equipment and walkie-talkies. Use real input electrodes on real human skin! Leonardo Da Vinci guided philosophers to discuss about human soul only after they have decided how to measure the soul. You have something to be measured, so do it.

Comment: What if ill just use the Netech EEG and ECG generate instead of real input. Isnt it a 10 microVolt or 1mV coming from generator and human skin is the same 10uV and 1mV provided same amplitude or is the one from the generator still stronger in other ways??

Comment: Real wires and a real human are  real noise catching antennas. I guess the boxed devices and the special test signal cable from instrument to instrument allow much less ways for external noises to get in.  I mean there's a full metal jacket, no wires outside the shielding.

Comment: The cable used is just alligator clips with ordinary wire used in circuit, but there is no noise except if you put the system near a transformer. So I guess it would take near proximity to RFI sources to produce noises and ordinary radio and television signal in the air waves can't cause noises. Do you know how to compute the magnitude of the signal that would be induced in the system enough to disturb say 10uV or 1mV signal? I need to see the computation as originally asked. Thanks.

Comment: Such calculations are useless without knowing the amp and its cables and the human under measurements exactly. Move a cable 10 cm and get totally different noise sensitivity profile. The result depends on geometry and properties of all parts. Calculation needs exact circuit, material and geometry data and high end electromagnetics simulation software which may have rent $10000,- per year or month.  The programs solve 3D vector field differential equations in given geometry - something a little more complex than Ohm's and Kirchoff's laws or circuit analysis with freeware programs. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, given the source of interference and setup is the same except the input of 10uV vs 1mV. Do you believe the 10uV (microVolt) can more easily suffer more interference (or easier) than the bigger 1mV signal?

Comment: No real measurements = no knowledge. No crystal ball available. In EMC test laboratories the systems are placed in front of radio transmitting antennas. Another (much more uncertain) possibility is to connect a radio signal generator to the biosignal input to see how many volts or milli-, micro,- nano- or picowatts the device tolerates in different frequencies. Then one can separately calculate (a worst case estimate) what field strength vs frequency is needed to make the worst case  measurement target+cables combination to catch enough to drive the measurements out of promised tolerances.

Comment: @Jtl in case the input happens to work linearly with a certain caught noise, 10 uV biosignal  may get through with no disturbances in the measurement. 1mV biosignal + the exactly same noise can get clipped. I have here no crystall ball  which tells how your device works. You have the device, so you are the one who has the theoretical possibility to reverse engineer it. Or to make measurements.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that the transmitted RFI level isn't what causes the clipping or distorts the signal.  If I transmit a signal at 5000 watts, but from 5000 kilometers away, it will cause no interference in your circuit.  Conversely, a few milliwatts can totally destroy your signal if all of the interference signal gets into your circuit.

The question you need to answer is "How much received signal can my circuit tolerate?"

How much of the transmitted signal gets into your circuit depends on the power of the transmitted signal, the distance to your circuit, and how well shielded your circuit is.

It also depends on how much your circuit "acts like an antenna."

If you have long, exposed wires then your circuit will act more like an antenna and pick up more interference.

Two circuits that do the same job but which are constructed differently will pick up different levels of interference from the same source.  If one has no shielding and uses long, unshielded leads then it will pick up more interference than one that is properly shielded and uses shielded leads.

Aside from that, you can add filters to the leads to the circuit to reduce the effects of interference.

There is no simple, single answer to your question.  It's like asking "How high is up?"

---

What you have to do is to determine what frequency range you are interested in, then filter out anything outside that range.

For your EKG  signals, you'd want to filter out anything over 150 Hz - that's the [standard range for EKG signals used medically.](https://www.gehealthcare.com/insights/article/a-guide-to-ecg-signal-filtering)

It seems that [EMG signals can contain content at higher frequencies.](https://www.noraxon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/ABC-EMG-ISBN.pdf)  Still, these are audio frequencies and below and are easily separated from radio frequency interference using appropriate filters.

The input leads to your circuits would typically have filters that remove radio frequencies (hundred kHz and up.)  After that would come filters to select just the interesting part of the signal.  These filters would be passive for the radio frequencies while the filter to select the interesting signal would typically be an active composed of passive components and and amplifier.

Comment: If the Netech EEG and ECG sine wave generator has produced very clean 10uV and 1mV output then it means at that particular time, there is no RFI reaching the circuit so it can be used as detector of RFI presence nearby? at least to get some quick check